# Use vector layer attributes as edge properties of a QgsGraphArc with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, qgis-network-analysis

With PyQGIS 2.18 I created a `QgsGraph` as describe in the PyQGIS developer cookbook, Release 2.18, ch. 21.2, pp. 95-97. In the cookbook it says

*"Vector layer attributes and length of an edge can be used as the properties of an edge"*.

By now, my source vector layer has variety of attributes (road names, landuse, ...) I would like to use as edge properties for styling purposes, labeling etc of my network analysis results.

I tried to access the edge properties by `QgsGraphArc.properties()` but this gives my a one-element list of the cost attribute used for graph analysis.

So the Question is: How to use the attributes of the source vector layer for a `QgsGraph` as properties of its `QgsGraphArc`s (or edges respectively)?